# Displaying a plist in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, plist

Edit:

Ok so basically, I have a UITextView on on view controller, along with a save button.  When the save button is tapped, I want the text of the UITextView to be saved to the plist.  Then, on a totally separate view controller, I want a UITableView to display the saved files.  Hope that makes sense.

Ok,

I have been trying this forever and can't get anything to work.  My questions are: how do I add a string to a plist programmatically.  How do I display that plist in a UITableView?

Thanks,

Tate

Comment: If you want to 'save' the data you will need to addd the textView.text to the array (probably an NSMutableArray).  Then you will pass the reference tot he array to the view controller with the new table view so it can use it to populate the view.  You can optionally save the data array to the device if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how you add a NSString to a NSArray which is stored in a plist file.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];
[mutableArray addObject:@"FooBar"];
[mutableArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[mutableArray release];
```

But there is no need to save the file to disk every time you add a string. Most likely it is okay to save it to disk when you leave the view and/or when you leave the app.

You know already how to create a NSArray out of a plist file, so you can use this NSArray as datasource for your UITableView, there are dozens of tutorials for this, so I omit this part.

If you use the .plist to get some kind of synchronization between several viewControllers you are doing it wrong. In this case you should ask again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pList in you resources you can do it like this:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Workbook1" ofType:@"plist"];

//This will take care of all the data types, 
//so in the plist you can have dates, strings, numbers, dictionaries and arrays.        
NSArray *array= [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

Once you have your array you can use it as the dataSource for you `UITableView`.

To wire to plist you can use the method of most property list objects:

```
NSString* aString=@"Test";

[aString writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile];
```

or

```
NSArray* anArray;

[anArray writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile];
```

Comment: Ok I'm giving this a try right now, I'll let you know how it goes in a second.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to load the plist into an array.

Then you'll need to set the data in the cells as a normal table view.

If you want to add strings to the Plist, you'll need to save it to an array and then save the Plist file.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html